# oracle10g Regular expression Compare string

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

I want to compare two strings and check if any of the characters are there second string

```
String1 2345
string2 162
```

This should result **True** as 2 is available string2

```
 String1 2345
 String2 167
```

This should result **False** as none of characters in string1 is present in string2

```
 String1 2345
 String2 1434789
```

This should result **True** as 3 is available string2

Answer (score 3):

Taking an example from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm), you could do something like so:

```
SELECT String2, String1
FROM ...
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (String2, '[' || String1 || ']');
```

The square brackets, `[` and `]` denote a set of characters which can be matched. For instance, `[abc]` will match either `a`, `b`, `c` or any combination of such letters, but will fail for something such as `def` since neither letters are present within the set.